# Scroll lock last section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a website where the penultimate section takes a fixed position and the last one goes over. However, the goal is for the last section to never be halfway through. To do this, after the penultima section is in a fixed position, I detect if the scroll comes from above. If it comes, at a certain point the page scrolls to the bottom. I'm having problems here because when the page does do the animation of scrolling the last section gets stuck. Can you help me?

```js
function fixe_section(scrollTopPx){
 if(scrollTopPx>$('.section2').offset().top){
 $('.section2 div').css({'position':'fixed', 'bottom':'0', 'z-index':'-1'});
}
else{
 $('.section2 div').css({'position':'static', 'z-index':'0'});
}
}

$(window).scroll(function(event){
  scrollTopPx = $(window).scrollTop();
  fixe_section(scrollTopPx);
});
section_move();

function section_move(){
 var start_mov = $('.section2').offset().top+$('.section2').height()/2;
 var move_to = $('.section3').offset().top+$('.section3').height();
 var lastScrollTop = 0;

 $(window).scroll(function () {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  
     if(st>lastScrollTop){
      if(st>start_mov){
          $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop: move_to
          }, 600);
          return false;
      }
     }
 lastScrollTop = st;
    });
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
section div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section1">
  <div class="green"></div>
</section>
<section class="section2">
  <div class="red">TESTING</div>
</section>
<section class="section3">
  <div class="blue"></div>
</section>
```